# How to save an entire array of Integers?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I need to save all of the data in an array of Integers. I am in Swift Playgrounds, I tried using UserDefaults to save them this to store in

```
let savedSugarArray = [UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sugarArray")]
```

This to place the data in savedSugarArray

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(sugarArray, forKey: "sugarArray")
```

Since I'm using Swift Playgrounds I think I'd rather not use core Data since it is so lengthy. Is there another way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. What's with the square brackets in the 1st line of code? 2. Why do you mistakenly use `setValue(forKey:)` to save a object in `UserDefaults`? Use `set(forKey:)`. 3. What is your actual question?

Comment: I use the square brackets to make it of type Int array. My question is how to save the array so I can exit the app and still use the data from the previous entries

Comment: You already have code to save the array. So what problem are you having (besides the issues in my 1st comment)?

Comment: It won't  save. Exactly what I said before, the code is there obviously but it doesn't save the array.

Comment: Did you do what said and use `set(forKey:)` instead of the incorrect `setValue(forKey:)`?

Comment: Yes I did this UserDefaults.standard.set(sugarArray, forKey: "sugarArray")

Comment: @johnd337 to load the array you can use UserDefaults method arrayForKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserDefaults doesn't function the same in playground (Xcode 8.2.1) as it does in a project. Normally, you'd use the following:

Set:

```
let integerArray: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]
UserDefaults.standard.set(integerArray, forKey: "sugarArray")
```

Get:

```
if let integerArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "sugarArray") as? [Int]{
      //good to go
}
else{
     //no object for key "sugarArray" or object couldn't be converted to [Int]
}
```

However, to show that UserDefaults don't function the same in playground, simply copy this into your playground:

```
let integerArray: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]
UserDefaults.standard.set(integerArray, forKey: "sugarArray")
if let integerArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "sugarArray") as? [Int]{
    print("UserDefaults work in playground")
}
else{
    print("UserDefaults do not work in playground")
}
```

Comment: So what am I putting in the after the if statement. It's not showing anything in the array?

Comment: Normally you'd use the integerArray object. What good is it to use UserDefaults in the Playground? Doesn't make a lot of sense to me conceptually.

Comment: It's for a contest. I have to use a Swift playground.

Comment: I have successfully used UserDefaults for saving a String from a textField

Comment: I've never tried UserDefaults in playground, but I just did and it doesn't work. See the edited answer.

Comment: But what is the purpose of using an if statement.

Comment: I would suggest some reading on basic logic statements if you're asking what an if statement does/is used for. This should be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)

Comment: UserDefaults have a method specific for loading arrays https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414792-array `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "sugarArray") as? [Int] {` The only case you need to use object for key is to test if a key exists or not

Answer (score 0):

I think an extension can be really helpful here

```
extension UserDefaults {
   open func set(_ intArray: [Int], forKey defaultName: String) {
      let array: NSArray = intArray as NSArray
      set(array, forKey: defaultName)
   }

   func intArray(forKey defaultName: String) -> [Int] {
      var result: [Int] = []

      let found = value(forKey: defaultName) as? NSArray ?? []

      found.forEach {
         guard let item = $0 as? Int else {
            return
         }
         result.append(item)
      }

      return result
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([1,2,3,4,5], forKey: "sugarArray")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let sugarArray = UserDefaults.standard.intArray(forKey: "sugarArray")
```

Little explanation

the array of `Int` is converted to an object of `NSArray` and then saved to the `UserDefaults`

to get the array we get an object and try to parse it as `NSArray`
then we convert each item in the found array to an `Int`

then return the result